# Why does Webpack Task Runner for Visual Studio not allow multiple output files?

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-2017, output, task-runner-explorer

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with the Webpack Runner extension installed. I have the following TS files:

- /Scripts/TypeA/A.ts
- /Scripts/TypeB/B.ts

And would like to transpile them to the following:

- Scripts/TypeA/A_transpiled.js
- Scripts/TypeB/B_transpiled.js

There is no "clean" way of doing that!

1. Following the "multi-compiler" code example, defining multiple export seems to be supported in Webpack: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-compiler. However, this does not work in VS 2017. I get the following error:

   > Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema
2. I can use the "name" parameter as shown here:

   `output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './Scripts/')
   }`

but it would still create all files in the same folder (Scripts).

3. The best, but hacky way of doing this was to make the entire path a part of the entry name as shown here:

   `entry: {
      'Scripts/TypeA/A_transpiled': './Scripts/TypeA/A.ts',
      'Scripts/TypeB/B_transpiled': './Scripts/TypeB/B.ts'
   },
   output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '')
   }`

This would create the files in the correct location. However, this has other drawbacks. For example, exporting and using your ts files as a library would then require you to use the entire path (if you use the "name" parameter as the library name), which could get cumbersome.

This seems like a huge drawback/missing functionality. Am I missing something, or did I do something wrong when using the "multi-compiler" approach? Why is something this simple not implemented in Webpack Task Runner? Should I consider getting rid of Webpack altogether and just rely on Gulp or Grunt?

Comment: Sounds like the extension is not using the version of Webpack that you are expecting. Try configuring Web Package Management in VS. Validate that it works by running Webpack directly from a command prompt.

Comment: I re-installed webpack using npm so that I have the latest version of webpack (3.11.0). I was able to the "multi-compiler" approach listed in the link above. Thank you!

Comment: you should post that as an answer. It's really easy for all these IDE plugins to make assumptions about environmental variables and package manager versions and all kinds of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-installed webpack using npm so that I have the latest version of webpack (3.11.0). I was able to the "multi-compiler" approach listed in this link:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-compiler